# how to properly iterate over a list and a dictionary values?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I am trying to iterate first over a list and then over a dictionary values:

The idea is to `print()` all posible combinations between list elements and dictionary values.

Here's what I got so far:

```
countries = ["Mexico", "Brasil", "Argentina"]
job_catalog = {"operations director":["director de operaciones", "director of business operations"]}

for country in countries:
    for job_title in job_catalog:
           report_name=str(job_catalog.values())+'-'+country
           print(report_name)
```

Console output:

```
dict_values([['director de operaciones', 'director of business operations']])-Mexico
dict_values([['director de operaciones', 'director of business operations']])-Brasil
dict_values([['director de operaciones', 'director of business operations']])-Argentina
```

Expected output:

```
#director de operaciones-Mexico
#director de operaciones-Brasil
#director de operaciones-Argentina
#director of business operations-Mexico
#director of business operations- Brasil
#director of business operations-Argentina
```

What am I missing?
Is there any other simpler way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over **`dict`** values:

```py
countries = ["Mexico", "Brasil", "Argentina"]
job_catalog = {"operations director": ["director de operaciones", "director of business operations"]}

for country in countries:
    for job_titles in job_catalog.values():
        for job_title in job_titles:
            report_name = f"{job_title}={country}"
            print(report_name)
```

**Output:**

```
director de operaciones=Mexico
director de operaciones=Brasil
director de operaciones=Argentina
director of business operations=Mexico
director of business operations=Brasil
director of business operations=Argentina
```

You can iterate over a `dict's values` and `dict's keys`:

```py
d = {"a": "b", "c": "d"}

for key in d.keys():
    print(key)

for value in d.values():
    print(key)

for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)**:

```
from itertools import product


countries = ["Mexico", "Brasil", "Argentina"]
job_catalog = {
    "operations director": [
        "director de operaciones",
        "director of business operations",
    ]
}

for a, b in product(job_catalog["operations director"], countries):
    print("#{}-{}".format(a, b))
```

Prints:

```
#director de operaciones-Mexico
#director de operaciones-Brasil
#director de operaciones-Argentina
#director of business operations-Mexico
#director of business operations-Brasil
#director of business operations-Argentina
```